# How to merge two files with one column into one file with two columns in Piglatin

Tags: ruby, perl, apache-pig

I have one file as

```
A  
B   
C
```

Other is

```
100  
101  
102
```

I want to merge these two files in PigLatin (i.e.merge first column with first column) in PigLatin

```
A 100      
B 101  
C 102
```

Comment: Why do you have `ruby` and `perl` tags?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. We need to see the program that you cannot get to work.

Comment: Use `RANK` and `JOIN`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request to write code, with no evident research or effort.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple :

```
File.write('first_file',<<_)
A  
B   
C
_
File.write('second_file',<<_)
100  
101  
102
_
```

I used [`IO::readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines) first to get all the lines from each of the files.

```
# strip method is used here to stripped out the line separator from
# the end of the each line.
ary1 = File.readlines('first_file').map(&:strip) 
ary2 = File.readlines('second_file').map(&:strip)
```

Then I used [`IO::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-open) method to open the file `new_file` in *write* mode. Read [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) to understand, why I used this method.

```
File.open('new_file','w') do |file|
    ary1.zip(ary2) do |a|
        file.write(a.join(" ")+"\n")
    end
end
```

[`IO::foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) method *executes the block for every line in the named `I/O` port, where lines are separated by `sep`*

```
File.foreach('new_file') do |line|
  puts line
end
# >> A 100
# >> B 101
# >> C 102
```

Comment: Why write the obscure `map(&:strip)` instead of `map { |line| line.strip }`?

Comment: I don't know. `map(&:strip)` is what *you* wrote.

Comment: First you tell me, why is it *obscure*? Do you find me first to use `map(&:strip)` ?

Comment: -1 for unnecessarily arcane code

Comment: @Borodin Okay.. I accepted.. your -1.. Be happy.

Comment: Please explain *"do you find me first to use map(&:strip)"*. I suggest that you shouldn't use `iterator(&:method)`, especially for questions like this.

Comment: I don't believe I was rude. On the other hand I have flagged your last comment as being `rude of offensive`. You must accept reasonable criticism, and I don't believe your cryptic solutions help most people who come to Stack Overflow for help.

Comment: @Borodin `map(&:strip)` is not obscure.  It may have seemed so after it was introduced in 1.9, but now that we're up to 2.1, it is "bread and butter" programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
use List::Util qw(pairmap);

use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my @file1 = read_file('file1.txt'));
chomp(my @file2 = read_file('file2.txt'));

write_file('outfile.txt', pairmap { "$a $b\n" } @file1, @file2);
```

Comment: This is basically a nice answer, but `File::Slurp` isn't a core module and would need to be installed. And you shouldn't recommend it without establishing that the files are less than a few gigabytes.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, I decided to go for brevity and clarity, and so figured having to install [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=File%3A%3ASlurp&mode=all) would be ok for some.  It's a nice module for cases like this.  It also required installing [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=List%3A%3AUtil&mode=all) on my system, as the core provided version didn't have pairmap.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, and may be worth a look. It expects the paths to the input files as parameters on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @fh = map {
  open my $fh, '<', $_;
  $fh;
} @ARGV;

while (grep { not eof $_ } @fh) {
  my @columns = map <$_> // 'empty', @fh;
  chomp @columns;
  print "@columns\n";
}
```

**output**

```
A 100
B 101
C 102
```

Comment: I like your style, taking it to the general case.  Btw, I think the `while (grep { not eof } @fh == 0) {` loop would be slightly more readable if it were written as `until (grep { eof } @fh) {`.  Isn't often where I find instances where until feels better than while, but I think this is one.

Comment: @Miller: I intended this as a bit of a joke, given the OP's rather odd question. But you're right about the `while` condition because it was completely wrong and I forgot to go back to fix it. Your fix isn't what I intended because it loops until *any one* of the files is at eof. I meant to loop until all of the files were at eof, and fix the empty columns in the next line. But that turned out too messy so I did it anyway and let the warnings talk about the mismatched files.

Comment: @Miller: Please don't use this as a pattern unless you have an unknown number of files. Mapping an array of file paths to an array of file handles is fine, but don't forget error handling!

Comment: @Miller: There was also another bug in my `grep { not eof } @fh` because there is a difference between `eof`, `eof()` and `eof($_)` and I guessed the default wrongly. Another warning against being too clever!